# Insert data from futureBuilder into table

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to display the data obtained from futureBuilder into the table, this is the code that I tried but when I run browse an error appears like this
[image]

```
         FutureBuilder(
      future: UserController.getActivity(_selectedUser),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData != null) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, position){
              var item = snapshot.data.elementAt(position);
              return Container(
            child: Table(
                children: List<TableRow>.generate(10, (i) {
                  return TableRow(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                  width: 0.5, color: Colors.grey))),
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                          child: Text(
                            //data[i].author.toString(),
                            "${item["activity"]["project"]}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(18),
                          child: Text(
                            //data[i].stars.toString(),
                            item["created_at"],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ]);
                })),
          );

            }
          );

        }
      },
    ),
```

if I use listView in displaying data, it becomes ineffective because the data is a lot

Comment: Have you tried to put your `TableRow` code inside the `ListView` `itemBuilder`?

Comment: @AugustinR I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

Error is here at this line

> itemCount: snapshot.data.length,

`length` is not found in the snapshot. You need to check the return type of future `UserController` what it's returning.

For being to verify your code that it's working fine you can set the default value

**Just to verify that UI working fine**

> itemCount: 10

*after that you need to check your return type.*

Comment: but displaying from the listView the Container return is correct ??, I guess from listView it can't be displayed in the table ??